# Shrink to fit not fitting for the whole A4 page width

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file in which the coding for the 'page' part is as below:

```
   @page { margin: 2% 0% 0% 2%;}
     .page {    BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px;}
        .pageBreak{ page-break-before: always;position:relative; WIDTH: 0px; } 
         .page1 { BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 675px; HEIGHT:900px; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px;} 


<table class="page1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

            <div
                style="z-index: 10; top: 10px; left: 14px; width: 730px; height: 1015px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
                <table width="730px" height="1015px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&#160;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
             //some code here......
</table>

<table class="page">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

            <div
                style="z-index: 10; top: 10px; left: 14px; width: 730px; height: 1015px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
                <table width="730px" height="1015px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&#160;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div> 
             //some code here......
</table>
```

Our client requirement is that when print option is selected as 'Shrink to Fit',the print preview and the print is displaying the page which is not getting fit to the A4 size width and height.It is leaving a lot of space at the right border and bottom. So,please suggest as what can be made to meet the requirement i.e. selecting the page with 'Shrink to Fit' should result in page occupying the 90% of whole A4 sheet leaving the other 10% for borders. The issue is observed for all the browser versions of IE and FF. Chrome is not in our scope.

Comment: What is this in your styles? `@page { margin: 2% 0% 0% 2%;}`

Comment: it is an existing code,but the above property is used to set the margins.The margin property defines the outermost portion of the box model, creating space around an element, outside of any defined borders.

Comment: Thanks . You enlightened me about the margin. The @ syntax makes no meaning BTW. You can try using `print` media query for print page specific styles.

Comment: what exactly should i use the code? I am a newbie to HTML CSS. Can you please let me know?

Comment: however when i select fit to page'100%',the page is as expected. But only when i select Shrink to fit is the issue.